# Saving Web.Config Changes using SPWebConfigurationModification in SharePoint 2010

Tags: configuration, sharepoint-2010

I have seen numerous examples on some SharePoint blogs regarding the use of the SPWebConfigurationModification class to modify SharePoint's web.config.

However, I noticed some examples call the update method at different times. For example:

```
myWebApp.Update();

myWebApp.Farm.Services.GetValue<SPWebService>().ApplyWebConfigModifications();
```

Or

```
myWebApp.Farm.Services.GetValue<SPWebService>().ApplyWebConfigModifications();

myWebApp.Update();
```

Which is the correct way? The reason why I ask is because I get a "A web configuration modification operation is already running." error when deploying a custom page which requires modifications to the web.config to be made on load balanced server.

I am sure it is probably due to the fact that the web.config changes are not being saved correctly across multiple farms.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct order is `ApplyWebConfigModifications()` then `Update()`.  Are you encapsulating that code in `SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges`?

Comment: I haven't done that. Will that correct the "A web configuration modification operation is already running." error I am getting? So is that a permissions issues then?